# How to create a Django queryset from a list of values

Tags: python, django

I am given a list like so

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This list matches the id's stored in a django model we will call Books.

**I am trying to return a queryset of Books with the id's in the list.** I am thinking of using Q objects and grab them by doing something like this

`Books.objects.filter(Q(id = 1) | Q(id=2) | Q(id=3) | Q(id=4))`

Now i would just use the index like this:

`Books.objects.filter(Q(id = a[0]) | Q(id=a[1]) | Q(id=a[2]) | Q(id=a[3]))`

BUT, These list will be varying in length up to around 30 and hardcoding the index wont work, and hardcoding the query won't satisfy the varying length of lists.

Is it possible to go this route? And if so, how can I accomplish returning the books with the id's that match the list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) here:

```
Books.objects.filter(pk__in=a)
```

As the documentation says:

> **In** a given iterable; often a `list`, `tuple`, or `queryset`. It’s not a common use case, but strings (being iterables) are accepted.

Comment: If you could, how could i accomplish this with a list of strings instead of integers?

Comment: @Mfreeman: the same way, just `a = ['foo', 'bar']`, for example `Books.objects.filter(title__in=a)`.

Comment: Are you sure? in the docs it shows `Entry.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 3, 4])
Entry.objects.filter(headline__in='abc')` as equivalents to these sql commands `SELECT ... WHERE id IN (1, 3, 4);
SELECT ... WHERE headline IN ('a', 'b', 'c');`

Comment: I've tried to just put in the array of strings, but come up with nothing when i know they are in fact values in the model im querying

Comment: @Mfreeman: I'm quite sure, are you sure that the list contains the exact same string (no leading/trailing spaces, etc.)? Did you pass it as a *list* of strings, not a single string.

Comment: Yeah I've made sure it is a list of strings eg  ["hello", "world"] and that they are the exact same string as in the models

Comment: @MFreeman: well you can check the query it generates with `print(Books.objects.filter(...).query)`. But I'm actually really surprised.

Comment: Ok so I was using another filter search on a column that wasn't supposed to be there, I got it to work, Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

For a simple case, use `__in` lookup as per [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57169993/5246906)

However, Q objects connected with `|` is not magic syntax, so it ought to be possible to build chains of them using  loops, like

```
qlst = []
for x in some_iterable
    qel = Q( something based on x)
    qlst.append(qel)
if len(qlst) == 0:
    # oops -- must handle somehow, or code below will crash
filter = qlst[0]
for qel in qlst[1:]:
    filter = filter | qel

queryset = Books.objects.filter( filter)
```

Caveat: I've never actually needed to try this.